# Commerce custom template field not showing up in Solr schema

Tags: solr, sitecore-commerce

In the solr portal, the new field is not displayed either in schema or in the search results.
Using XP 10.1 & XC 10.1  in my local machine.

1. Created a new template using composer.
2. Updated the data templates and refreshed the commerce cache in XP.
3. Following this [article](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/101/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/adding-a-property-field-to-an-index.html), added these settings in *C:\inetpub\wwwroot\CommerceMinions_Sc\wwwroot\data\Environments\PlugIn.Search.Solr.PolicySet-1.0.0.json*

   {
   "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr.SolrIndexFieldConfiguration,
   Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Search.Solr",
   "Name": "StringPropertyIndexName",
   "Type": "System.String",
   "Handler": {
   "$type": "Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog.ComposerFieldHandler,Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog",
   "ComposerSource": {
   "ViewName": "Vehicle",
   "PropertyName": "StoreID"
   }
   }
   }
4. Added this patch config.

   [image]
5. Rebuilt the master index.

Comment: Starting with SXC 9.3.0 and higher, commerce entities are indexed by Commerce Engine and not Sitecore. So, please follow the instructions listed under https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/100/sitecore-experience-commerce/en/adding-a-property-field-to-an-index.html and then bootstrap your commerce engine. Once bootstrapped, restart all your commerce instances and then trigger the index rebuild. If you followed the instructions correctly, Solr should show the new custom fields information.

Comment: Also, make sure the SolrIndexFieldConfiguration is added to both master and web indexes. They both are located in the same policy JSON file.